# Batch File input validation - Make sure user entered a letter

Tags: batch-file, user-input

As the title suggests, How can I ask for user input and if it is not a letter goto :this.
I am making a batch file to search a specified network drive and return a list of .exe files.

```
I have done this but with to much code, i.e. 
If "%choice%"=="a" goto :scan
If "%choice%"=="b" goto :scan
etc.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set letters=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
set /P drive=Enter drive:
rem Be sure that just one character is processed
set drive=%drive:~0,1%
rem Try to remove the character from letters; 
rem if the result is not equal: the character IS a letter
if "!letters:%drive%=!" neq "%letters%" goto scan
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it working...  I will just go back to how I had it before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this easier with VBScript, but here's a batch solution:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p choice=
set map=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
for /l %%i in (0,1,25) do (
    if /i %choice% equ !map:~%%i,1! goto scan
)
exit
:scan
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it working...  I will just go back to how I had it before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET letter=&SET /p letter="Please choose a single letter "
IF NOT DEFINED letter ECHO No choice made&GOTO :eof
ECHO "%letter%"|FINDSTR /i /b /e /r \"[a-z]\" >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO NOT a single letter) ELSE (ECHO "%letter%" is a single letter)
```

Almost there - only appears to fail if entry contains `"`